# R: prevent source re-compilation using devtools::install

Tags: r

I am in the process of developing an R package with external source code that takes a long time to compile. While compilation time isn't a big problem for a one-off installation, I have to routinely reinstall the package to test new additions. Is it possible to prevent re-compiling the source code if there haven't been any changes to it?

I don't necessarily need this to be automated, but I can't figure out a manual solution either. As my source code is in Rust, the following serves as the most representative example I have (note that it requires Rust cargo to be installed):

```
git clone https://github.com/r-rust/hellorust
Rscript -e "devtools::install('hellorust', quick = TRUE)"
```

When I run the above, I see that the `hellorust.so` file has been created in the `src` directory, but how do I make `devtools::install()` use this file rather than recompile everything? It doesn't seem like `devtools::install(quick = TRUE)` or `devtools::install(build = FALSE)` are meant for this...

Alternatively, is it possible to achieve the desired behavior on the Rust side of things? I don't understand why cargo would recompile everything if there haven't been any changes and the target directory is still there. That said, I'm quite new to Rust and compiled languages in general so my understanding of the broader concepts involved here is unfortunately quite limited...

I would also be interested to learn if there is a better way to test R packages during development than manually reinstalling them.

Comment: After this, doesn't `library(hellorust)` work without recompiling everything? The point of `install` is to compile everything and install it within your library as if you had done `install.packages`.

Comment: @r2evans Yes, but this is more a development question rather than a user question. I'm writing the package and my workflow thus far has been to 1) implement a new function, 2) install the package and test it 3) iterate to work out bugs (often reinstalling 5-10 times as I forget stupid things). And I can't do that when compilation takes 5 minutes. So I'm looking for tips to either a) allow installation without forcing a needless recompile (when src didn't change) or b) adjust my workflow so that I can test new additions to the package in an iterative manner without constantly reinstalling

Comment: I tend to use `load_all` instead of `install`, as it does not recompile each time and still allows me to test.

Comment: @r2evans Great, thanks! This seems like exactly what I was missing as I have been hung up on the full install process for some reason... I took another look at devtools and seems like I should probably be integrating `test` function as well using `testhat`. I'll have to play around with it a bit but I'd imagine this would be the answer to my underlying problem.

Comment: Unit-testing can be a life-saver, especially with long-life packages (as opposed to shorter-term projects). I confess many of my (internal) packages have relatively poor coverage, and I'm reminded of that every time a client says *"this used to work but doesn't anymore"*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments by r2evans, the final answer seems to be that this isn't what `devtools::install` is for.

As per the `devtools` [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/devtools/versions/1.13.6), there are three main tools for "frequent development tasks":

- `load_all`
- `document`
- `test`

Of these `load_all` "simulates installing and reloading your package, loading R code in R/, compiled shared objects in src/ and data files in data/". By default, `load_all()` will not recompile source code in src/ (unless the `recompile` flag is set to true).

So the answer is to use `load_all` as opposed to `install` during package development and manually control when to compile the source code using something like `devtools::compile_dll`.